# How do you convert a series of javascript (jQuery) button "on clicks" into a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, optimization

I have a series of buttons (25 of them) used to set the height of something in a web application. I know it's an odd way of doing it, but there's a reason. **Each button has an id equivalent to the height it sets, in inches, from 0 to 24, and they all share the HeightButtons class**. Here's what I have so far, manually typing it all out:

```
$('#0').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 0;
}$('#1').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 1;
}$('#2').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 2;
}$('#3').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 3;
}$('#4').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 4;
}$('#5').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 5;
}$('#6').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 6;
}$('#7').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 7;
}$('#8').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 8;
}$('#9').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 9;
}$('#10').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 10;
}$('#11').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 11;
}$('#12').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 12;
}$('#13').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 13;
}$('#14').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 14;
}$('#15').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 15;
}$('#16').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 16;
}$('#17').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 17;
}$('#18').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 18;
}$('#19').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 19;
}$('#20').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 20;
}$('#21').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 21;
}$('#22').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 22;
}$('#23').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 23;
}$('#24').click()(function() {
    LiftHeight = 24;
      }
```

Obviously, it's very inefficient. How do I put this into a loop?

Comment: You could almost just give all the buttons a class, bind a single click to the class and then read a data value and set the height accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you give them a class also, like this:

```
$('.dynHeight').on('click', function() {

     LiftHeight = this.id;

});
```

Comment: @SheikhHeera: It's valid in HTML5.

Comment: @Blender, It also works (but not valid) in prior to `HTML5`, tested in chrome.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use a loop at all. Give those buttons a class and maybe a `data-` attribute:

```
<button class="height-setter" data-lift-height="12">Click me</button>
```

And then attach an event handler to them:

```
var lift_height = 0;

$('.height-setter').click(function() {
    lift_height = $(this).data('lift-height');
});
```

Or, if possible, use their order:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <button>One</button>
    ...
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
var lift_height = 0;

$('.buttons button').click(function() {
    lift_height = $(this).index();
});
```